# Extjs how to make the scrollbar appear?

Tags: extjs

I need to show a scrollbar as soon as the form is wider then containing container. I set the property autoScroll: true on the container, but it's not working. Is there anyway to get the result I need ?

Here is the working example

http://jsfiddle.net/mQC3B/2/

The code

```
Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {

    layout: {
        header: false,
        type: 'border',
        padding: 0
    },
    items: [{
            region: 'north',
            padding: '0 150 0 150',
            height: 36,
            html: 'header'
        }, {
            id:'mainPanelContainer',
            autoScroll: true,
            padding: '0 150 0 150',
            region: 'center',
            items:[
                {
                    xtype:'form',
                    items:[{
                        xtype: 'container',
                        flex: 1,
                        layout: 'anchor',
                        items: [{
                            xtype: 'textfield',
                            fieldLabel: 'Name',
                            name: 'Name'
                        }, {
                            xtype: 'textfield',
                            fieldLabel: 'Name',
                            name: 'Name'
                        }, {
                            anchor: '95%',
                            xtype: 'htmleditor',
                            fieldLabel: 'Popis',
                            name: 'Description',
                            height: 240,
                            width: 450
                        }]
                    }, {
                        xtype: 'container',
                        flex: 1,
                        layout: 'anchor',
                        items: [{
                            xtype: 'textfield',
                            fieldLabel: 'Name',
                            name: 'Name'
                        }, {
                            xtype: 'textfield',
                            fieldLabel: 'Name',
                            name: 'Name'
                        }, {
                            xtype: 'textfield',
                            fieldLabel: 'Name',
                            name: 'Name'
                        }, {
                            xtype: 'container',
                            margin: '0 0 8 0',
                            layout: 'hbox',
                            items: [{
                                xtype: 'textfield',
                                fieldLabel: 'Name',
                                name: 'Name'
                            }, {
                                xtype: 'textfield',
                                fieldLabel: 'Name',
                                name: 'Name'
                            }]
                        }, {
                            xtype: 'textfield',
                            fieldLabel: 'Name',
                            name: 'Name'
                        }]
                    }]
                }
            ]
        }, {
            region: 'south',
            height: 25,
            padding: '0 150 0 150',
            html: 'Copyright &copy; 2013'
        }]
});
```

**EDIT**

After adding layout: 'fit' to mainPanelContainer the scrollbar appears, but it's not possible to scroll to the hidden right side of the form.

http://jsfiddle.net/mQC3B/3/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your fiddle for your edit, change:

```
padding: '0 150 0 150',
```

in the center region to:

```
margin: '0 150 0 150',
```

Believe it or not, extjs layouts do not handle the padding property very well.  I have run into this before with my layouts.  It looks like in your example, margin will work to achieve what you want.  Another way to achieve the same result is to nest another level deep with a border layout and add east and west regions with the empty space to mimic the behavior of the padding.

Comment: After changing the padding to margin the scrollbar looks fine. But still I cannot scroll to right side of the form on a smaller screen.

Comment: Take out the layout: "fit"  and give the form a width.

Comment: Also beware of using `border: 0` - that switches off scrollbars aswell.

Comment: another fine example of how ExtJS is horribly broken

Answer (score 2):

`autoScroll: true` is the way to do it, but you'll need to have all of your layouts correct for it to work.  Try putting `layout: 'fit'` on your `mainPanelContainer` and/or your `form`.

Comment: I added the layout fit setting to the mainPanelContainer. The scrollbar is shoven but you can not scroll it to the right end of the form. http://jsfiddle.net/mQC3B/3/

Answer (score 2):

Basically you just need to add the autoScroll property like:

```
autoScroll: true
```

Answer (score 0):

if you remove the nested form and just put the padding on the overarching container (the viewport in this example) it's seems to get you what you're after from what i understand.

http://jsfiddle.net/mQC3B/15/

```
Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {

    padding: '0 150 0 150',

    layout: {
        header: false,
        type: 'border'
    },
    items: [{
        region: 'north',
        height: 36,
        html: 'header'
    }, {
        id: 'mainPanelContainer',
        autoScroll: true,
        region: 'center',
        xtype: 'form',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'container',
            flex: 1,
            layout: 'anchor',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: 'Name',
                name: 'Name'
            }, {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: 'Name',
                name: 'Name'
            }, {
                anchor: '95%',
                xtype: 'htmleditor',
                fieldLabel: 'Popis',
                name: 'Description',
                height: 240,
                width: 450
            }]
        }, {
            xtype: 'container',
            flex: 1,
            layout: 'anchor',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: 'Name',
                name: 'Name'
            }, {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: 'Name',
                name: 'Name'
            }, {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: 'Name',
                name: 'Name'
            }, {
                xtype: 'container',
                margin: '0 0 8 0',
                layout: 'hbox',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Names',
                    name: 'Name'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Name',
                    name: 'Name'
                }]
            }, {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: 'Name',
                name: 'Name'
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        region: 'south',
        height: 25,
        html: 'Copyright &copy; 2013'
    }]
});
```